# Como adicionar um vetor dentro de uma classe?

Tags: python-3.x

Meu professor passou um trabalho que diz o seguinte:

> Crie uma classe Aluno, que possui como atributo um nome e cpf. Crie outra classe
> chamada Equipe, que possui como atributo uma lista de participantes do tipo Aluno e outro
> atributo chamado projeto. Crie uma terceira classe chamada GerenciadorEquipes. Essa
> classe possui como atributo uma lista de todas as equipes formadas. Ela deverá possuir o
> método criarEquipe, que recebe uma lista de alunos de uma equipe e diz se a equipe pode
> ser formada ou não. Caso não haja nenhum aluno da equipe a ser formada em uma outra
> equipe com o mesmo projeto, então a equipe é criada e acrescentada à lista. Caso contrário
> é​ ​informada​ ​que​ ​a​ ​equipe​ ​não​ ​pode​ ​ser​ ​criada.

Eu estou com o meu código da seguinte maneira.
[Link aqui](https://repl.it/LHJG/1).

Minha pergunta é:

Como eu adicionou o vetor dentro da classe Aluno, ou como eu adiciono a classe Aluno dentro do vetor.

Estou tentando resolver essa questão que tá me dando uma dor de cabeça.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É o seguinte. Existem alguns erros e práticas que não muito boas no seu código. Vou tentar mostrar no seu prório código o que estou falando. Mas antes disso, eu gostaria de te explicar algo sobre arrays. Um array em python pode ser formado de qualquer conjunto de elementos de qualquer tipo (inteiros, floats, strings, objetos, etc), então se você quiser adicionar um objeto da classe Aluno em um array, basta fazer array = array + objeto.
Vamos ao código para eu te mostrar algumas coisas. Meus comentários são antecedidos de ###.

```
#coding: utf-8

#== CLASSE ALUNO ==#

#Adicionar quantidade de alunos usando vetor

quantidadeAlunos = input ("Informe a quantidade de alunos participantes: ")  ### Não precisa dessa variável para o problema

numAlunos = quantidadeAlunos ### Não precisa dessa variável
nomes = [] ### Não precisa dessa lista (ou array)
cpfs = [] ### Não precisa dessa lista

#Classe aluno
class Aluno():
    #Atributos
    nome = input ("Insira seu nome: ") ### Fazer um input dentro de uma classe me parece deselegante. Eu não faria isso. Até porque a questão não pede. Depois eu te mostro uma maneira melhor para você conseguir testar se está funcionando.
    cpf = input ("Insira seu cpf: ") ### Mesma coisa que o de cima

    #Métodos
    def __init__(self, nome = nome, cpf = cpf): ### Aqui vc pode colocar def __init__(self, nome, cpf):   caso vc tire os inputs de cima
        self.nome = nome
        self.cpf = cpf[:3] + "." + cpf[3:6] + "." + cpf[6:9] + "-" + cpf[9:]

    #def printAluno(self):
    #   print ("Nome: %s - CPF: %s" % (self.nome, self.cpf))

p = Aluno() ### Aqui, para instanciar um objeto Aluno, vc deverá passar como argumento os atributos nome e cpf, dessa forma: p = Aluno("joãozinho", "16734624789")   caso você tire os inputs também.
p.printAluno()

#== CLASSE EQUIPE ==#

class Equipe():
    nome = input ("Insira seu nome: ") ### Mesmo argumento da classe anterior
    cpf = input ("Insira seu cpf: ") ### Mesmo argumento

    def __init__(self, nome = nome, cpf = cpf): ### Aqui é o pulo do gato. Você deve receber uma lista (de alunos) e um projeto, então fica assim: def __init__(self, lista_de_alunos, projeto):
        self.nome = nome ### Aqui consequentemente fica: self.lista_de_alunos = lista_de_alunos
        self.cpf = cpf ### E a mesma coisa aqui para projeto: self.projeto = projeto

    def printAluno(self): ### Isso pode ser uma sobrecarga do operador print. Não é pedido no problema. Você pode fazer para conseguir printar o seu objeto no final, mas não vou entrar nesse detalhe. No código que eu fizer em baixo você vai ver um __str__(self), que é justamente o que esse cara faria.
        print ("Nome: %s - CPF: %s" % (self.nome, self.cpf))

### Aqui, para testes podemos criar uma lista de alunos assim: lista = [Aluno("Joao","123"),Aluno("Maria","145")]
### E podemos também criar um projeto assim: projeto = "lavar louça"
p = Aluno() ### Aqui você pode instanciar um objeto da classe Equipe dessa forma: equipe1 = Equipe(lista, projeto)
p.printAluno()

### Daqui para baixo deixo com você. Se você entender realmente o que fiz em cima, pode fazer o de baixo sozinho.
#== CLASSE GERENCIADOR DE EQUIPES ==#

class GerenciadorEquipes():
    nome = input ("Insira seu nome: ")
    cpf = input ("Insira seu cpf: ")

    def __init__(self, nome = nome, cpf = cpf):
        self.nome = nome
        self.cpf = cpf

    def printAluno(self):
        print ("Nome: %s - CPF: %s" % (self.nome, self.cpf))

p = Aluno()
p.printAluno()
```

Vou colocar a parte do código que eu comentei reescrita corretamente aqui em baixo.

```
#coding: utf-8

#== CLASSE ALUNO ==#
class Aluno():
    def __init__(self, nome, cpf):
        self.nome = nome # Atributo nome (ok)
        self.cpf = cpf[:3] + "." + cpf[3:6] + "." + cpf[6:9] + "-" + cpf[9:] # Atributo cpf (ok)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Nome: " + str(self.nome) + " - CPF: " + str(self.cpf)

# TESTE DA CLASSE ALUNO #
aluno_exemplo = Aluno("Joao","12345678901")
print aluno_exemplo


#== CLASSE EQUIPE ==#
class Equipe():
    def __init__(self, lista_de_alunos, projeto):
        self.lista_de_alunos = lista_de_alunos # Atributo lista de participantes (ok)
        self.projeto = projeto # Atributo projeto (ok)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Nome: " + str(self.lista_de_alunos) + " - Projeto: " + str(self.projeto)

# TESTE DA CLASSE EQUIPE #
equipe_exemplo = Equipe([aluno_exemplo, Aluno("Maria","12345257901")], "Projeto Abacaxi") # Apenas com dois alunos para facilitar a vida :D
print equipe_exemplo
```

Comment: Poxa! Tirou muitas outras dúvidas minhas. Com isso eu consigo desenrolar. Você comentou as outras duas classes, esse foi o que tirou muitas das minhas dúvidas. Eu tinha apenas copiado e colado, nem tinha tentado implementar alguma coisa. Ainda não terminei esse trabalho. Mas vai dá certo! Obrigado pela ajuda.